# How to show new website design to client from a github branch

Tags: github, branch

I have created a website for a friend which I have published on GitHub and deployed using Netlify.
However as my knowledge is improving I have created a branch off of the main repository and completely redesigned the site.

How can I now show this to my friend remotely?
As I understand if I commit this to main this will change the published website which I do not want to do yet as the changes haven't been agreed?

Is there a way to create a GitHub page from that branch so I can send him a link to view what I have created?

Comment: I found out from a friend that I am able to create another site on Netlify that points to the branch of the main repository and then Netlify gives me a dummy domain link that I can then share with my client for him to view the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you create a second empty GitHub repository in which you push tour second branch.

You can then build the GitHub pages for that second repository (using [GitHub Action workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73144097/6309) and a [starter workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main/pages)), and show the alternative version, using the second GitHub Pages URL.

Comment: Thank you. I found out from a friend that I can actually host the branch on Netlify and share a link to my client

Comment: @JoeGodwin Good solution indeed. Upvoted.